# find exec cp - copy files without overwriting duplicates

Tags: find, cp

I've got a few directories with matching file names:

```
Foo/
  one.pdf
  two.pdf
  three.pdf
Bar/
  one.pdf
  two.pdf
  three.pdf
Baz/
  one.pdf
  two.pdf
  three.pdf
```

...and I want to move all files into a single directory called "all_unsigned".

When I run this command:

```
$ find . -type f -name *.pdf -exec cp {} ./all_unsigned/ \;
```

...I end up with only one instance of each file name since the names match. How can I move all files without collisions? I'm fine with something like prepending the folder name to each file name, etc. A really gnarly one-liner is preferred to some kind of multi-line script.

Comment: Does your system's `cp` support a `--backup=numbered` option?

Comment: Do not forget the quotes: `-name *.pdf` => `-name "*.pdf"`

Comment: @steeldriver no, I don't have that option